# How to test index.js with server.listen() from another file

Tags: jestjs

I have Jest run on my app which returns a table of results files that pass or fail. The first one is for index.js:

```
File                   | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s
index.js               |       0 |        0 |       0 |       0 | 1-7
```

I don't understand how to test this index.js with Jest.

```js
require('newrelic')
const config = require('./config')
const server = require('./server')
const logger = require('./logger')

server.listen(process.env.PORT || config.port, () => {
  logger.info(`Started on port ${server.address().port}`)
})
```

Does someone know how to make a test that will give me 100% in each column of the result table?

Comment: I wouldn't test that file _at all_ at the unit level. Leave it to integration or E2E testing, it doesn't do anything bar start up the server, and you'd find out pretty promptly if that wasn't happening.

Comment: @jonrsharpe well i need each column to get at least 80% completion for the build to pass in my openshift pipeline. So I was trying to get these 8 lines to pass which would get me to 80%, rather than do other files that are more complicated.

Comment: Then the problem is the thoughtless rules, not the coverage of this file.